# Does SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition exist?

Tags: windows, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

On my server, I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition installed, and setup don't want to upgrade it to SQL Server 2012 Express.

Does SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition exist?

Comment: Why downvotes without comments?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It exists at least [on the MSDN download site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/downloads/hh442898#searchTerm=SQL%20Server%202012%20Developer%20Edition&ProductFamilyId=0&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0). Also, according to the [SQL Server 2012 Licensing FAQ](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/F/7/4F74E127-827E-420D-971F-53CECB6778BD/SQL_Server_2012_Licensing_Datasheet_and_FAQ_Mar2012.docx), “Developer, Express and Compact Editions will also continue to be distributed without licensing or pricing changes”.